# C# how to break public Void

Tags: c#, public, void

I have an class like this (this is an example ) I need return whole of class from everywhere I need it

```
Line1 :Public void test(bool start)
Line2 :{
Line3 :  if (start) //do something;
Line4 :  else   // i use else for update with help other code and... forget it
Line5 :  {
Line6 :   if (xxX)
Line7 :      if (sadasdas)
Line8 :          if(sdaeqwr324f)
Line9 :             if (Asdasdsa)
Line10:                  for (int a=0;a<6;a++)
Line11:                    {
Line12:                     if (c[a]==1321334)
Line13:                       {
Line14:                        t=c[1];
Line15:    /* <<< i neeeed  reset trace of test to first line of test  Line16 :>>>*/
Line17:                       }
Line18:                     }
Line19:     there are about 400 lines codes like Up at under of this line  }
Line20:}
```

My target is line 15 – if I add a return at The tracer jump to line 17 – I need  tracer jump to line 2
Sorry for my bad English ( I search to find why to solve it but I cant find anythings )

Comment: Could it be the "return" keyword you are looking for? I am not sure I understand the question

Comment: Why edit my question ??? i dont neeed it every people know it - i have allot of If in the if if i want break it from third if i just break current if and my trace go to next

Comment: That's horrible. Refactor your code.

Comment: tnx for comment there is why to do it ?

Answer (score 3):

To "break" from a function use `return`:

```
public void test(bool start)
{
  if (start) //do something;
  else   // i use else for update with help other code and... forget it
  {
     //do somethings (it is loop )
     pleas reset trace of test to first line of test
     return; // This ends the method, and returns to the caller
  }
}
```

Comment: Retorn is not good way becaus i have alot if in the if at it about 400 lines code

Comment: @ehsanwwe The number of lines of code shouldn't be a problem - just place the `return` at the spot where you want to end execution.

Comment: tnx to commenting :* i test it, just tracer terurn the last If for example 3 lines at up and i skip the if at up if i want reset from first line ( i need return whole )

Comment: i found a good way using GOTO